# Call method from other method within Ember Service

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm just learning Ember.js and ran into a little snag. I have a Service where I want to call another method I have defined within the same object, like so:

```
export default Ember.Service.extend({
  myMethod: function() { ... },

  otherMethod: function() {
    this.myMethod(); // <---- this doesn't work
    this.get('myMethod')(); // <---- also doesn't work
    Ember.run.bind(this, this.myMethod)() // <---- no dice
  }
});
```

Is there any way to do this? I would greatly like to reuse code within my codebase.

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is really short on any kind of detail, e.g. how you are initializing and calling `myMethod()` on your service. But, you shouldn't extend `Ember.Service` but `Ember.Object`, and you should initialise it correctly: http://emberjs.com/guides/understanding-ember/dependency-injection-and-service-lookup/

Comment: ...this is part of an Ember training course, so I'm just doing it how they're telling me I should. I'm not sure what other kinds of details are necessary. Shouldn't I be able to call the method of an object from within itself?

Comment: Assuming you're creating some sort of new object with this class, and then calling `serviceObject.otherMethod()` you should have no problem doing just that. There's nothing in the code you've shown which would prohibit this, so it must be how you create or use it.

Comment: i think you're missing the point of the question, or i'm not explaining it well enough. within the definition of the object, i have two methods: `a()` and `b()`. I want to call `a()` from within `b()`. so far I haven't found a way to do this.

Comment: And again, calling `this.a()` from `obj.b()` would work just fine (it's just Javascript, nothing Ember specific) as long as you initialise the object correctly *and* you call that initial `otherMethod()` as a method on that object, but you're not showing the code doing that.

Comment: Inside otherMethod, what value you are getting for "this" ? It might not be giving reference of your ember service. There you need to find the reference of your service method from the "this" reference.. Also it depends from where otherMethod is getting called as it defines the this reference for it.. I also faced similar issue in view, where I was not able to call other function as it was giving me reference of window and not view. Let me know if you need that example. Thanks @Jason

Comment: Swati is correct, your context isn't the object, how is otherMethod being called?  That's likely where you're context is being foobared.

Comment: You can make an Ember twiddle now!

Comment: How do you call otherMethod ?

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that you've already gone on from this point. But here's an ember-twiddle just in case that demonstrates how a service can reference its own methods. Like it was said in the comments, it's a javascript thing about `this`.

https://ember-twiddle.com/7caf29fe1df7f36e6e3e49578fc3aed3?openFiles=services.movie-service.js%2Ctemplates.components.movie-viewer.hbs

Comment: I know this is old, but how would I make this twiddle work? I basically added one function call, `displayMovies()`, to the action you made in your twiddle https://ember-twiddle.com/27aebdeb9ab75841ee16b3dbd8df3f76?openFiles=services.movie-service.js%2Ctemplates.components.movie-viewer.hbs

Comment: Hi @MarcusRenno, if I read your twiddle correctly you'd like to trigger displaying movies with the movie service. I would advise against it though. The movies service is a singleton and might outlive the component you plan to display things on, or you might want to share it between several different components. Instead, storing the data with the service and consuming it with components is probably your best bet

Comment: That's a good suggestion, but the problem I tried to ask was different. The function displayMovies was just created to try to use a function within another function in case one function starts to get big. I like to keep functionalities separate so it's easier to read/maintain